# Usage : « Que signifie ? » (Via Mala, de John Knittel, Albin Michel, p. 348)

Tags: usage, emploi-absolu

> *Via Mala*, John Knittel
>
> — Il n'est rien arrivé. Seulement… j'avais besoin d'être un peu seule pour réfléchir; il fallait que je me dise au revoir.
> — Te dire au revoir? Que signifie?
> — Parce que… je t'appartiens maintenant. C'est si étrange de se dire que demain nous serons des gens mariés.

Il me semble n'avoir aucune notion d'utilisation en emploi absolu de « signifier » lorsqu'il a le sens élémentaire qu'on lui donne dans cette phrase ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/signifier), « Avoir pour sens, pour signification »).

S'agit-il d'un helvétisme ou bien est-ce que cet emploi serait possible en français de France, ou encore est-ce que l'on doit voir dans cette construction un usage qui ne s'est pas répandu ?

Comment: Cela pourrait aussi être justifié par le contexte historico-géographique : personnage non francophone ou expression vieillie.

Comment: John Knittel a écrit Via Mala en Anglais. Ainsi, "Que signifie ?" vient dun traducteur qui aurait pu écrire quelque chose de moins insolite, comme "Ce qui signifie ?".

Comment: En anglais, c'était "Good-by to yourself? What do you mean?" Pas insolite du tout.

Comment: @PeterShor En français on se serait attendu à la même chose que la traduction mais avec un « cela » en plus (« que signifie cela ? »), ou plus couramment à « Qu'est-ce que ça signifie ? » (placement bizarre de « cela » et « ça », mais il n'y a pas d'autre ordre de placement).

Comment: Ici, intuitivement, j'aurais inséré trois points de suspension avant le point d'interrogation, comme si c'était une phrase non achevée. "Que signifie?" tout seul ne me semble pas correct.

Comment: @LPH: By *pas insolite du tout*, I meant the English wasn't at all unusual. To me, the French seems to be lacking an object, and it looks like a lot of people who the better French than me agree.

Comment: @PeterShor I did understand that the English was normal. You probably meant "subject": "que" is the object; "cela" or "ce que vous dites" or "cette remarque", etc., is the subject.

Comment: Que signifie [ « — … que je me dise au revoir. » (repris en « — Te dire au revoir ?… placé avant)].  C'est une transcription ‘libre’ de l'oral sur du papier, rien d'autre. Les « … » en changerait le contexte et le niveau d'expression du locuteur.

Answer (score 0):

J'imagine qu'il s'agit d'une ellipse:

Que signifie ce non-sens ?

Comment: On ne peut pas déduire ce qui a été supprimé, et de ce fait on ne peut pas parler d'ellipse. Il y a trop de possibilités entre par exemple « Que signifie votre remarque ? » et « Que signifie ce non-sens ? ». S'il y a une ellipse elle est de la sorte que l'on marque par la ponctuation « … » (voir [commentaire de user Frank](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/52776/usage-que-signifie-via-mala-de-john-knittel-albin-michel-p-348/53083#comment110460_52776)), mais dans ce cas on ne parle pas d'ellipse;  anglais : « … » est appelé  « [ellipsis](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/ellipsis)».